# List indices must be integers, not str from user input

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
Tools_List=["Hoe","Pitchfork","Shovel"] #`list`
print(Tools_List)
Tools=input("What tools do you want? ")  
print(Tools_List[Tools])
```

Comment: sorry this autism, i am bad at python

Comment: Convert input from string to int

Comment: cheers big man sorry for being autism

Answer (score 0):

One can only index with one index as a time, wheres your prompt asks for 'Tools' plural.  I suggest (with the int correction, and lower-case names)

```
tools = ["Hoe","Pitchfork","Shovel"]
print(tools)
tool = int(input("What tool do you want? "))
print(tools[tool])
```

Comment: yeah i did this big man thanks for the help though